# Find line in text file, check for text in between?

Tags: file, text, find, set, text-files

Question about Batch/Windows/CMD:

I would like that my batch file can search for a line (which I already achieved, but what comes next not), it looks like this:

```
<name>MyName</name>
```

It needs to find the text in between <name> and </name>. After that it needs to set that as a variable (%name%).

Does anyone have any idea?

EDIT: if someone wants to give an answer, please list the code. Perl is OK, but this should be open-source and not everyone has Perl.

Comment: If you enclose code-like text in backticks (the '`' character), you can display what you type verbatim. This will avoid confusion - I had to read your question a few times to figure out that you were substituting parentheses for angle brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done this way (assuming your input is in file "test1.html"):

```
findstr "<name>" test1.html > temp1.lis
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=>" %%i in (temp1.lis) do @echo %%i > temp2.lis
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=<" %%i in (temp2.lis) do @echo %%i > temp3.lis
```

The first line is a guard that only HTML/XML tag 
"name" will match in the two FOR lines  (you may
already have done this). The result is saved in a temporary
file, "temp1.lis".

The second line capture what is to the right of the first
">" - in effect what is after "<name>". At this stage
"MyName</name" is left in temporary file "temp2.lis" (as
the closing tag also contains ">"). Note the double "%"s
(%%i) as this is in a BAT file (if you want to test directly
from the command line then it should only be one "%").

The third line capture what is to the left of the first "<"
- this is the desired result: "MyName" (is left of "<" in
"MyName</name"). The result is in variable %%i and you 
can call a function with %%i as a parameter and access the 
result in that function (in the FOR line above the function 
was the built-in "echo" and the result thus ended up in 
temporary file "temp3.lis" by the redirection of standard 
output)

---

Note that the above only works if

```
<name>MyName</name>
```

is the first HTML/XML tag in a line.

If that is not the case or you want a more robust solution
you can instead call a function in the first FOR line (that
receives %%i as the first parameter). That function can then
replace "<name>" with a single character that you are
sure is not in the input, e.g.:

```
set RLINE=%MYLINE:<name>=£%
```

Explanation: if the input line is in variable %MYLINE% then
"<name>" will be replaced with "£" and the result will be
assigned to variable %RLINE%.

The reason for the replace is that the delimiters for the
FOR loop are single character only.

You can then use "£" as a delimiter in the FOR loop (to extract what is 
to the right of "<name>" - as before):

```
echo %RLINE%>temp5.lis
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=£" %%i in (temp5.lis) do @echo %%i > temp6.lis
```

You have to repeat this technique for "</name>"
(but only if <name>MyName</name> is not
the first HTML/XML tag in a line).

So as you see it is possible, but is quite painful.

Comment: you say that above only works if is the first line... but you use findstr so it searches in the hold doc right?

Comment: No, not the first line. The first tag in a line. If a line contained "<someOtherTag>Unrelated content</someOtherTag> some more words <name>MyName</name>" then the relatively simple first solution would not work.

Comment: Can you list some sample input in your question?

Comment: o no thats totally fine. Every tag is done on a seperate line... So it's ok.

Comment: can you give me a total code at the first one (so </name> also included)

Comment: What do you mean by "at the first one"? The line with "findstr"?

Comment: the hole script, i mean can you make it total, becaue you said "You have to repeat this technique for "</name>"."

Comment: But you don't need it as there is only one HTML/XML tag per line for your input data. You can just use the 3 lines in the beginning of the answer (I will edit my answer to make this more clear).

Comment: forget about it, its working like a charm. i see that was only meant for whats after the first code... Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Learn [Perl](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/start.html), it's made for exactly that kind of thing.

Comment: Now you have 2 problems. http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/22/558007.aspx

Comment: No, really, Perl is great for manipulating text files. Let me add to your joke: simply using a computer gives you two problems. Opening a browser and entering a question on SO gives you two problems. If you don't want to learn how to use good tools, good luck accomplishing anything.

Comment: the link you give is just 'a little' outdated... i know what your going to say 'it are the basics'... But if you want to give me a tutorial, please give me a more updated one, ok. But thanks anyways.

Comment: Find them online or buy an O'Reilly Perl book.